# Plotting a numpy array with 256 columns used for k-means

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with this shape: (109, 256) Every row is a frame and every column is a value of the frame's histogram (8 bits).

With k-means I cluster the histograms to get a resume of the frames. I want something like this:
[image: clustering]
Where every cluster should be a "scene" with similar histograms.

But how can I plot a representative graphic of the k-means process with 256 columns??

I'm trying with this typical example:

```
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow')
```

But yeah, it shows only 2 columns and it doesn't represent the problem. Any help? I'm really new on Python and machine learning.

PD: my k-means code works well and it clusters the way I want, but I don't know how to represent it correctly.

Comment: can you explain why you have 256 columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You always represent k-means clustering results on two axis. Those axis can be picked randomly. The only way you can include more attributes is by adapting the size of your points to another variables (for example the higher the income the bigger the point) or by having different color shades. 
Otherwise, you seem to have done everything correctly, you have to stick to two variables for your axis and can't integrate more.. 
You can decide on creating more plots with different axis and create a grid (often this doesn't add much information though)